# How can I iterate through <div> elements with different class names with python 3.7 and selenium webdriver?

Tags: html, selenium, python-3.7

I'm trying to make a reddit bot that gives me a report about my profile and
now I have to find which of my comments has the most number of likes.

All the comments are inside  elements with different and random class names, but inside these, I found that there is always a  element with the start of the class name that is "comment t1_" and then random characters.

SO I thought to make a loop that could iterate through every  element in the source code and checks if "comment t1_" is in the class name.

Only then I found out that the method "find_element_by_class_name" is outdated and no longer available.

The class name is the only way to access to the elements in the page because the xpath is too long, and almost random. Here are 2 examples that I confronted to find something in common:

```
1)//[@id='SHORTCUT_FOCUSABLE_DIV']/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div

2)//[@id="SHORTCUT_FOCUSABLE_DIV"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/div
```

these are the xpaths of the s who contain "comment t1_".

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: why can't you use find_element_by_class_name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following xpath to find the elemet:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'comment t1_')]
```

PS: You can always use find_element_by_class_name. It would be nice if you could paste the error you are getting so that we can try to help you solve it.